# Why is my player animation still happening when I am not moving?

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I have it so that my character will play a walking animation when they move left or right, and when they stop moving they are idle. The animation part works fine, but when I let go of left/right, it still plays and the player never goes idle. The code for my player animation and player controls are below.

```
def animation_state():
    global player_surface, player_index, player_rect
    

    player_index += 0.15
    if player_index >= len(player_right_walk):
        player_index = 0
    
    if LEFT == True:
        player_surface = player_left_walk[int(player_index)]
    elif RIGHT == True:
        player_surface = player_right_walk[int(player_index)]


    if LEFT == False and RIGHT == False:
        player_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_idle_right.png').convert_alpha()
    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_idle_left.png').convert_alpha()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_idle_right.png').convert_alpha()

    
    screen.blit(player_surface,player_rect)

player control
def player_control():
    global LEFT, RIGHT
    player_velocity = 0
    player_gravity = 0
    

    player_gravity += 3
    player_rect.y += player_gravity
    if player_rect.bottom >= 500:
        player_rect.bottom = 500
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player_velocity -= 11
        LEFT = True
        RIGHT = False
        if player_rect.x < -50:
            player_rect.x = 800
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player_velocity += 11
        LEFT = False
        RIGHT = True
        if player_rect.x > 800:
            player_rect.x = -50

        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_velocity = 0

    player_rect.x += player_velocity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not reset `LEFT` and `RIGHT` if no key is pressed. Set `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to False before checking the keys. Set `LEFT` or `RIGHT` depending on the key that is pressed:

```py
def player_control():
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    LEFT = False
    RIGHT = False
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player_velocity -= 11
        LEFT = True
        if player_rect.x < -50:
            player_rect.x = 800
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player_velocity += 11
        RIGHT = True
        if player_rect.x > 800:
            player_rect.x = -50
```